# Считать файлы по Bluetooth в xamarin.android или java

Tags: java, android, c#, xamarin, bluetooth

Есть 2 телефона на android. Телефоны подключены друг другу по bluetooth. Можно ли с 1 телефона считать файлы другого телефона и как это сделать? Был бы очень полезным пример на java или c#.

Comment: Что значит, считать? все на устройстве? или передать и прочитать?

Comment: Старайтесь писать более подробные вопросы. Опишите что именно у вас не получается. Если есть, добавьте ваш код в вопрос.

Answer (score 0):

Вот пример bluetooth-чата от гугл: [ссылка](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/development/+/25b6aed7b2e01ce7bdc0dfa1a79eaf009ad178fe/samples/BluetoothChat).

Вполне логично, что можно отправлять данные побайтово по блютуз. Пусть другое устройство формирует вам ответ в нужном формате. Не очень понятно, что вы подразумеваете под "считать файлы", но передавать их, естественно, можно. Если вам нужно просто список файлов и папок, чтобы получить информацию о файловой системе, значит сначала другое устройство должно получить эту информацию, потом поместить это в нужный формат данных (в строку, например), и уже после этого отправить вам в виде байтов.

Копировать код оттуда я не стану, а разобраться с этим, я думаю, вы сможете сами, пример хороший и комментариев в том коде много :)

Answer (score 0):

Альтернатива для Xamarin.Anroid такого же проекта, как предложил @Peter Samokhin
https://github.com/xamarin/monodroid-samples/tree/master/BluetoothChat

Библиотека для работы с Bluetooth:
https://developer.xamarin.com/api/namespace/Android.Bluetooth/